# Delete From SQLite Using Select Statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following `SELECT` statement,

```
SELECT * From MyTable as t
WHERE
t.Key1 =
(SELECT Max(r.Key1) From MyTable as r
WHERE (Key2 = t.Key2 AND Key3 = t.Key3 AND Key4 = t.Key4))
AND
(Key2 = t.Key2 AND Key3 = t.Key3 AND Key4 = t.Key4)
```

which selects all the records I wish to delete from `MyTable`. However when I try to actually delete the records i.e. by changing `SELECT *` to `DELETE`, I get an error and I believe this is because you cannot use aliases with a `DELETE` statement.

How then would I go about deleting these selected records from `MyTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed not possible to use an alias for the table name in a DELETE statement.

However, that table still has a name.
As long as all other instances of this table have an alias, you can unambiguously refer to any of them:

```
DELETE From MyTable
WHERE
MyTable.Key1 =
(SELECT Max(r.Key1) From MyTable as r
WHERE (Key2 = MyTable.Key2 AND Key3 = MyTable.Key3 AND Key4 = MyTable.Key4))
AND
(Key2 = MyTable.Key2 AND Key3 = MyTable.Key3 AND Key4 = MyTable.Key4)
```

(The last line of this query does not make sense, because it is not part of the subquery and `Key2` and `MyTable.Key2` refer to the same table.)